# Problema con tecla enter y materialize autocomplete

Tags: html, jquery, materialize

Al usar la tecla enter, en el objeto de materialize `autocomplete` me refresca toda la página.

```
function insertar(response) {
    var ingredientes={};
    for (var i = 0; i < response.ingredientes.length; i++) {
        var tmp=response.ingredientes[i].Nombre;
        ingredientes[tmp]=null;
    }
    console.log(ingredientes);
    $('#search').autocomplete({
        data: ingredientes,
        onAutocomplete: function(txt) {
          M.toast({html: "Estoy autocompletado"});
        },
        limit: 5, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    });
}
```

no sé si me falta algo de configurar, les agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias.
edit: el código html que se usa es el siguiente

```
<nav class="buscar">
            <div class="nav-wrapper" >
                <form>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input id="search" type="search" class="autocomplete" required>
                        <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons brown600">search</i></label>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: El autocomplete está en un form? Si es así el form se envía a través del intro también

Comment: si, gracias, ese era el problema c: